# Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running a react application and it shows the following error:

```
Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code
```

what does this error mean and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using react-helmet?
You can fix this problem by using side effect.

Like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        <Helmet>
            <title>Hello Doctors - {children}</title>
        </Helmet>
    }, [children])
```